# Book or text for an introduction to pseudo differential operators on manifolds.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, microlocal-analysis

What text or book  is quite enjoyable to start (anti dummies) in the study of  differential operators (and pseudo) on manifolds? I have been studying the Wong book to understand pseudo differential operators and I find it quite educational and enjoyable. Will there be any similar about manifolds? I would like to understand the process of how to go from operators on $\mathbb{R}^n$ to manifolds. That's my goal.
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can find this material in resources such as Michael Taylor's PDE II book, Hormander III (not exactly fun), these notes by Peter Hintz: [https://math.mit.edu/~phintz/files/18.157.pdf](https://math.mit.edu/%7Ephintz/files/18.157.pdf), and many more. For a semiclassical approach, see Zworski's book or the newer book by Dyatlov and Zworski (the former author has a pdf version on their website: [http://math.mit.edu/~dyatlov/res/res_final.pdf](http://math.mit.edu/%7Edyatlov/res/res_final.pdf)). Dyatlov also has some summarized notes here: [http://math.mit.edu/~dyatlov/semisnap/](http://math.mit.edu/%7Edyatlov/semisnap/) (see "Monday Aug 5").

The general idea is that a pseudodifferential operator on a manifold should "look like" a pseudodifferential operator in local coordinates. This needs some care, though (one gets a larger class than desired if no growth restrictions are placed on the Schwartz kernel). The above make this much more precise.

Comment: Thanks. Although I am looking for even more pedagogical and introductory. I saw the links and it is somewhat difficult to understand ...

Comment: I'm not aware of textbooks covering pseudodifferential operators on manifolds that don't come with some heavy background. You need to have a good understanding of pseudodifferential operators on $\mathbb{R}^n$ first. So, most books do all of the $\Psi$DO background first (manifold stuff either covered quickly or in an appendix), which means that there's a lot to read before you get studying them on manifolds.